# How to take the value of a specific key in MongoDB with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, key-value

I'm sure this is simple, but I need to pull a value from a key-value pair to check if it matches the username in session. (I'm using pymongo)

An example of one of the MongoDB object looks like this ('jam_or_event' is the collection name):

```
_id: ObjectId("5d44545037b30613b88ae587")
jam_title: "Test Jam 2"
genre: "Rock"
date_of_jam: "2 August, 2019"
jam_location: "Test Address 2"
jam_county: "Bristol"
jam_member_1: "TestUser2"
member_instrument_1: "Drums"
jam_notes: "Test 2"
jam_owner: "TestUser2"
```

The values change object to object, but I want to be able to pull the jam_owner value from the currently selected object, and ask if it's the same a the username of the user currently logged in. If they match, they'll have more privileges over the page.

Here's the code for the python function:

```
@app.route('/edit_jam/<jam_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_jam(jam_id):
    user_logged_in = 'username' in session
    the_jam =  mongo.db.jam_or_event.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(jam_id)})
    username=session['username']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_logged_in:
            jams = mongo.db.jam_or_event
            jams.update( {'_id': ObjectId(jam_id)},
            {
                'jam_title':request.form.get('jam_title'),
                'genre':request.form.get('genre'),
                'date_of_jam': request.form.get('date_of_jam'),
                'jam_location': request.form.get('jam_location'),
                'jam_county':request.form.get('jam_county'),
                'jam_member_1':request.form.get('jam_member_1'),
                'member_instrument_1':request.form.get('member_instrument_1'),
                'jam_notes':request.form.get('jam_notes'),
            })
            return redirect(url_for('get_jams'))
    return render_template('editjam.html',
        jam=the_jam,
        instruments=mongo.db.instruments.find(),
        counties=mongo.db.counties.find(),
        username=session['username'])
```

I then want to be able to say, in the html

```
{% if jam_owner == username %}
xyz
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure if you mean this but I hope I understand Correctly although it seems very simple to ask about.

Ok so this Code is returning the Object from Mongo db:

```
the_jam =  mongo.db.jam_or_event.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(jam_id)}) # so the_jam will hold the Object (Dictionary) from Mongodb.
```

you can access your jam_owner or whatever it is called with:

```
the_jam[key] # as key you want to get jam owner value I think so it will be the_jam["jam owner"]
```

and since you have the name of the user in the username variable you can compare it:

```
if username == the_jam["jam owner"]:
# ....
```

Comment: Sorry, basilisk, I don't think I explained myself very well.

This is just an example, so it could be any object, with all different values, and I need to essentially find out the value of the jam_owner.

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: I'm hoping to essentially say: if username == jam_owner: xyz

Comment: I don't get it. can you please modify the Question and describe what is your desired output and how you data is structured etc.. ? that will help you to get your answer faster

Comment: Just updated, hopefully that makes more sense, thanks for looking at this one!